# Chrome CustomTab error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method startActivity

Tags: java, android, start-activity, fitbit, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to connect fitbit with my app using chrome custom tabs. But I am getting following error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method startActivity(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat' appears in /data/data/com.life.myApp.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-25.0.1_a32c44837a06d33159cc113605aa7f1cb8d56675-classes.dex)
>                                                                       at android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(CustomTabsIntent.java:200)
>                                                                       at com.life.myApp.app.ThirdPartyLibrary.TrackersDevies.FitBitTracker.LoginFitTrackers.onActivityCreated(LoginFitTrackers.java:208)
>                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2289)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1008)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1164)
>                                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1557)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    incremental = true;

}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.life.myApp.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 20
    versionName "1.1.0.15"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.7.0'
compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.2.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.liulishuo.magicprogresswidget:library:1.0.9'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0'

}

configurations {
compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
/*
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}*/
```

Here is my java code.

```
speedUpChromeTabs();
        weakReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(getActivity());

        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME, mCustomTabsServiceConnection);
        customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(mCustomTabsSession)
                .setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.blue))
                .setShowTitle(true)
                .build();
     url = url + "?time=" + (new Date().getTime());
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624768/unable-to-start-chrome-customtabsintent-in-my-android-app), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296639/fatal-exception-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetsliste), and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643596/i-upgraded-android-from-targetsdk-22-to-23-and-im-getting-a-nosuchmethoderror) but no success so far.

Comment: add java code also

Comment: The error is saying `No static method startActivity(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat; or its super classes`, probably error is on activity.

Comment: Hi @W4R10CK thanks for reply . Can you explain me in detail please.

Comment: let me explain once i see the activity code. Please post that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I updated that code in my app and working perfectly.Because 
>   documentation says 23 version and it throws this error.

```
mCustomTabsServiceConnection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, CustomTabsClient customTabsClient) {
                mCustomTabsClient= customTabsClient;
                mCustomTabsClient.warmup(0L);
                mCustomTabsSession = mCustomTabsClient.newSession(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mCustomTabsClient= null;
            }
        };

        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(getActivity(), CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME, mCustomTabsServiceConnection);

        mCustomTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(mCustomTabsSession)
                .setShowTitle(true)
                .build();
```

and changed in gradle file also

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.MyApp.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did is that

```
 compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0+'
```

Because the documentation says 23 version and it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have already using below sdk version set in one project

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
```

But the project where I am using Chrome Custom tab and getting the same exception

```
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
```

Please update the compile and target sdk version from 24 to 25